# Install libraries with NPM or import from CDN?

Tags: reactjs

I'm confused why all the React tutorials I'm using to learn React have me installing libraries through npm rather than importing through CDN's (React, Redux, Material UI, firebase, etc). I thought CDN's were more efficient.

Any guidance on this would be helpful (this is my first time using VS code and installing packages like this, the only other website I've programmed I just imported bootstrap and jquery through CDN and coded in notepad++ :/)

Comment: Well there are advantages, such as you may not want to use an entire library, and for a lot of libraries you can import only parts of it when importing via an NPM installed library, rather than fetching the **entire** lib from a CDN. But reasons aside, why WOULD you use a CDN? If you could bundle all your required code up in one neat package, or pull in like 12 different external resources at page load time, the former feels cleaner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you can of course use a CDN to import scripts into your application (with, for example a `<script>` tag) npm is useful in the fact that when you build your React app it will bundle all the required modules together.

This can be advantageous in the fact that your users don't have to download any scripts when your application loads (which can take some users with slower connections a long time) since everything is bundled within your React app. Some applications depend on a lot of dependencies, and forcing every new user to download each script individually can cause speed issues.

At the end of the day, I don't think there is a right or wrong answer as to whether you should use a CDN or NPM, just understand that when you use NPM it bundles the required scripts into your app when you run `npm run build` instead of the user having to download them when they visit your site.

Comment: OHHHH, that makes a lot more sense then. So it makes a custom bundle of only the parts of the library you use rather than having to download the entire library? If that's the case, now I can see why that might be useful. Sorry for such a beginner question, and thank you for the answer.

Comment: @BrettWilliams Yes, anything you import will be included, and yes it makes it so you don't have to download entire libraries

Comment: maybe late to the party, but I'd just add this bit:  
[...] your users don't have to download any **further** scripts **in addition to your application script**

Answer (score 1):

CDN's will only get you so far. In the industry you're going to be expected to have some experience with npm/yarn. If you keeping going down the frontend rabbit hole, you'll eventually run into things like Webpack and Babble which will help make your Javascript a lot more efficient and backwards compatible. Installing things through npm/yarn will also often offer a lot in terms of providing you with a better development environment (things like react-scripts, eslint, prettier, etc).